# Assembly error in loading a page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the error for in loading the pages for which i have back-end c# code

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load the assembly 'App_Web_mmypavdc'. Make sure that it is compiled before accessing the page.

Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ page language="C#" autoeventwireup="true" inherits="Registration, App_Web_mmypavdc" %>
Line 2:  <%@ Register Assembly="MSCaptcha" Namespace="MSCaptcha" TagPrefix="rsv" %>
Line 3:  

Source File: /images/journal/Registration.aspx    Line: 1
```

Comment: Have you configured your directory in IIS as an application?

Comment: what is the .net framework version? are you working with web sites our web applications?

Comment: i have published this using file system and transferred to server directly using core ftp

Comment: framework is 3.5 Mr.Marco Alves